# Tizen Studio Emulator failed to install

Tags: macos, emulation, tizen

I try to install Tizen Studio 1.2, but I can't install any emulator. I tried different different Emulators, meaning from different SDK.

I found the a suggestion to change the ownership of ~/tmp to user, but this seems to be the problem. Also I tried to install from IDE and CLI, but both didn't work.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.5.

Here is the log:

```
Start to install 'WEARABLE-2.3.2-Emulator'.
The target packages to install:
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86, 2.3.2-emulator-kernel-x86, 2.3.2-libav, tuntaposx, cocoasudo, 2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86]
Start to download the target packages.
Waiting for finishing the downloads of the packages...
Start to install the target packages.
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Creating new install-progress... 
  [2.3.2-emulator-kernel-x86] Creating new install-progress... 
  [2.3.2-libav] Creating new install-progress... 
  [tuntaposx] Creating new install-progress... 
  [cocoasudo] Creating new install-progress... 
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Creating new install-progress... 
Waiting for finishing the installations of the packages...
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Moving the files to the target directory...
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Checking the integrity of installed files...
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Executing the install-script...
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Script Output:
  tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
  Error: Error while running 'qemu-img'. Exit value : 133
  You can get more information in log file (/Users/marcelreimann/Documents/tizen-studio/emulator/vms/emulator-manager)
  Failed to create default emulator instance
  [wearable-2.3.2-circle-emulator-image-x86] Script ExitCode:
  2
  [2.3.2-emulator-kernel-x86] Moving the files to the target directory...
  [2.3.2-emulator-kernel-x86] Checking the integrity of installed files...
  [2.3.2-emulator-kernel-x86] Updating the package's state to 'Installed'...
  [2.3.2-libav] Moving the files to the target directory...
  [2.3.2-libav] Checking the integrity of installed files...
  [2.3.2-libav] Updating the package's state to 'Installed'...
  [tuntaposx] This package is already installed by other thread!
  [cocoasudo] This package is already installed by other thread!
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Moving the files to the target directory...
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Checking the integrity of installed files...
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Executing the install-script...
Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:548)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:623)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:508)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.Install.InstallProcess.run(InstallProcess.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: The error occurred while executing the install script.
    at org.tizen.manager.core.Install.ManagerableInstallerCallable.call(ManagerableInstallerCallable.java:112)
    at org.tizen.manager.core.Install.ManagerableInstallerCallable.call(ManagerableInstallerCallable.java:23)
    ... 4 more
Recalculating the install state by failure...
Refreshing the install state of other packages...
Failed to install... WEARABLE-2.3.2-Emulator
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Script Output:
  create emulator-install.sh
  + TIZEN_SDK_INSTALL_PATH=/Applications/tizen-studio
  + USER=marcelreimann
  + cp -pR /Applications/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.3.2/common/emulator/etc/emulator-ifup.sh /etc/
  + mkdir -p /Library/Extensions
  + cp -pR /Applications/tizen-studio/tools/emulator/etc/tap.kext /Library/Extensions
  cp: /Applications/tizen-studio/tools/emulator/etc/tap.kext: No such file or directory
  + rm -rf /Applications/tizen-studio/tools/emulator/etc/tap.kext
  + chown -R root:wheel /Library/Extensions/tap.kext
  + mkdir -p /Library/LaunchDaemons
  + cp /Library/Extensions/tap.kext/Contents/net.sf.tuntaposx.tap.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
  + kextutil -nt /Library/Extensions/tap.kext
  /Library/Extensions/tap.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
  + /sbin/kextload /Library/Extensions/tap.kext
  + FILE=/etc/sudoers
  + BACKFILE=/etc/sudoers.bak
  + TMPFILE=/etc/sudoers.tmp
  + MESSAGE='# Tizen SDK generated the following script. Do not modify.'
  + LINE1='User_Alias QEMUERS='
  + LINE2='Cmnd_Alias QEMU=/etc/emulator-ifup.sh, /etc/emulator-ifdown.sh'
  + LINE3='QEMUERS ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: QEMU'
  + count=0
  + [[ marcelreimann == '' ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' sudoers file.
  + count=1
  + [[ # sudoers file. == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#'
  + count=2
  + [[ # == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' This file MUST be edited with the ''\''visudo'\''' command as root.
  + count=3
  + [[ # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root. == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Failure to use ''\''visudo'\''' may result in syntax or file permission errors
  + count=4
  + [[ # Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' that prevent sudo from running.
  + count=5
  + [[ # that prevent sudo from running. == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#'
  + count=6
  + [[ # == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
  + count=7
  + [[ # See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file. == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#'
  + count=8
  + [[ # == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=9
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Host alias specification
  + count=10
  + [[ # Host alias specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=11
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' User alias specification
  + count=12
  + [[ # User alias specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=13
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Cmnd alias specification
  + count=14
  + [[ # Cmnd alias specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=15
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Defaults specification
  + count=16
  + [[ # Defaults specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_reset
  + count=17
  + [[ Defaults env_reset == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"BLOCKSIZE"'
  + count=18
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"COLORFGBG' 'COLORTERM"'
  + count=19
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"'
  + count=20
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"CHARSET' LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE 'LC_CTYPE"'
  + count=21
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"LC_MESSAGES' LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC 'LC_TIME"'
  + count=22
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"LINES' 'COLUMNS"'
  + count=23
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  # sudoers file.
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"LSCOLORS"'
  #
  + count=24
  # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "LSCOLORS" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  # Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
  + read line
  # that prevent sudo from running.
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"SSH_AUTH_SOCK"'
  #
  + count=25
  # See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  #
  + read line

  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"TZ"'
  # Host alias specification
  + count=26
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "TZ" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]

  + read line
  # User alias specification
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"DISPLAY' XAUTHORIZATION 'XAUTHORITY"'

  + count=27
  # Cmnd alias specification
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]

  + read line
  # Defaults specification
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"EDITOR' 'VISUAL"'
  Defaults env_reset
  + count=28
  Defaults env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  Defaults env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
  + read line
  Defaults env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
  + echo Defaults env_keep += '"HOME' 'MAIL"'
  Defaults env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
  + count=29
  Defaults env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
  + [[ Defaults env_keep += "HOME MAIL" == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  Defaults env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
  + read line
  Defaults env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
  + echo
  Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  + count=30
  Defaults env_keep += "TZ"
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
  + read line
  Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
  + echo '#' Runas alias specification
  Defaults env_keep += "HOME MAIL"
  + count=31

  + [[ # Runas alias specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  # Runas alias specification
  + read line

  + echo
  # User privilege specification
  + count=32
  root ALL=(ALL) ALL
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
  + read line

  + echo '#' User privilege specification
  + count=33
  + [[ # User privilege specification == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo root 'ALL=(ALL)' ALL
  + count=34
  + [[ root ALL=(ALL) ALL == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo %admin 'ALL=(ALL)' ALL
  + count=35
  + [[ %admin   ALL=(ALL) ALL == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=36
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
  + count=37
  + [[ # Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' %wheel 'ALL=(ALL)' ALL
  + count=38
  + [[ # %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=39
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Same thing without a password
  + count=40
  + [[ # Same thing without a password == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' %wheel 'ALL=(ALL)' NOPASSWD: ALL
  + count=41
  + [[ # %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo
  + count=42
  + [[ '' == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Samples
  + count=43
  + [[ # Samples == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' %users ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
  + count=44
  + [[ # %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' %users localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
  + count=45
  + [[ # %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo '#' Tizen SDK generated the following script. Do not modify.
  + count=46
  + [[ # Tizen SDK generated the following script. Do not modify. == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + read line
  + echo User_Alias QEMUERS=marcelreimann
  + count=47
  + [[ User_Alias QEMUERS=marcelreimann == User_Alias QEMUERS=* ]]
  + echo 'find original script'
  ++ echo User_Alias QEMUERS=marcelreimann
  ++ cut -d = -f2
  + NAMES=marcelreimann
  + [[ marcelreimannx == x ]]
  ++ echo marcelreimann
  ++ tr , '\n'
  + for i in '$(echo $NAMES | tr "," "\n")'
  + [[ marcelreimann == \m\a\r\c\e\l\r\e\i\m\a\n\n ]]
  + echo 'already added the same user'
  + exit 0
  # Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
  # %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

  # Same thing without a password
  # %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

  # Samples
  # %users ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
  # %users localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
  # Tizen SDK generated the following script. Do not modify.
  User_Alias QEMUERS=marcelreimann
  find original script
  already added the same user
  delete emulator-install.sh
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Script ExitCode:
  0
  [2.3.2-emulator-qemu-x86] Updating the package's state to 'Installed'...
```

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: Try enabling the HW virtualization and GPU to enabled state in the emulator manager of the emu and then launch it and check.